# Trying to import xslt file/template into another xslt file and pass param. What am I doing wrong here

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT 2.0.    Here is my first file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:IAAXML="http://www.ibm.com/industries/financialservices/IAAXML">
    <xsl:import href="address.xsl"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Claim>
            <Contact>
                    <xsl:variable name="contact" select="//IAAXML:Invoice/IAAXML:roleInFinancialStatement/IAAXML:party[@xsi:type='IAAXML:Organization']/IAAXML:subOrganisation"/>
                    <xsl:call-template name="address">
                        <!-- <xsl:param name="contactParam" select="$contact"/> -->
                        <xsl:with-param name="contactParam" select="$contact"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
            </Contact>
        </Claim>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my second file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:IAAXML="http://www.ibm.com/industries/financialservices/IAAXML">
    <xsl:param name="contactParam" select="'default'"/>
    <!-- <xsl:param name="address" select="'default'"/> -->
    <xsl:template match="/" name="address" >
        <Address>
            <xsl:variable name="address" select="$contactParam[IAAXML:type/IAAXML:name='Department']/IAAXML:partyContactPreferences/IAAXML:contactPoints" />
            <AddressLine1>
                <xsl:value-of select="$address/IAAXML:addressLines" />
            </AddressLine1>
            <City>
                <xsl:value-of select="$address/IAAXML:city" />
            </City>
            <State>
                <xsl:value-of select="$address/IAAXML:state" />
            </State>
        </Address>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the following error:   IXJXE0781E: [ERR 0700][ERR XTSE0680] It is a static error to pass a parameter that is not a tunnel parameter 'contactParam' to a template that does not have a template parameter that has the same expanded QName.; SystemID: file:/C:/p4/xslPlay/partyTx/test.xsl; Line#: 10; Column# 62

What am I doing wrong?  How can I accomplish the passing of the parameter to the other file?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't your template have a parameter named contactParam in this case?:

```
<xsl:template match="/" name="address" >
    <xsl:param name="contactParam" select="'default'"/>
```

I have a feeling that's what the error is about.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you.  I declared the param outside of the template tag.  I pulled it inside and it works.